# Connect to created database with created user in a docker container

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, intellij-idea

i’m trying to connect to a postgre database which is inside a docker container. I´m creating the docker container with following command:

`docker run --name prodcoc -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=testuser -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test -e POSTGRES_DB=testDB postgres`

[image]

After the container is running I want to connect to the created database with the created user, but that seems not possible. Why can't I connect to the database which I'm creating with the enviroment variables?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my problem was to uninstall the local PostgreSql instance. I don´t know why I installed it but removing it solved my problem.
In windows this can be done in the Settings.